# How to demonstrate that continuous functions on a closed interval are Lebesgue integrable?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

So, I'm trying to prove that if $f$ is a continuous function defined on a closed interval $[a,b]$ then it is Lebesgue integrable. Here is my attempt based on what I've found on the internet so far:

Since $[a,b]$ is compact, any continuous function $f$ will be uniformly continuous. Therefore, for any $\epsilon>0$ we can find a delta which is independent from the points $x$ and $y$ (due to uniform continuity) that satisfies this statement:

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \exists \delta>0 , \forall x,y \in [a,b] \text{ such that } |x-y|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(y)|<\epsilon$$

Now we can partition the interval $[a,b]$ into $n$ subintervals $(I_n)$ such that each interval has a length less than $\delta$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$ we define $\displaystyle a_n = \sup_{x \in I_n}f(x)$ and  $\displaystyle b_n = \inf_{x \in I_n} f(x)$.

In other words, for any points in the subinterval $I_n$ we associate two numbers $a_n$ and $b_n$ whose values are determined by the supremum and infimum of $f$ on that subinterval respectively. It's obvious from the definition of $\sup$ and $\inf$ that in each subinterval we have $b_n \leq f \leq a_n$.

Now we define two simple functions that engulf the function $f$ from the above and the below by using $a_n$ and $b_n$ in the following way:
$\displaystyle \varphi_{\delta} = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i. \mathbb{1}_{I_n}$         and   $\displaystyle \psi_{\delta} = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i. \mathbb{1}_{I_n}$
Where $1_{I_n}$ denotes the indicator function on the subinterval $I_n$.

It is easy to see that $\psi_{\delta} \leq f \leq \varphi_{\delta}$   where the little subscript $_{\delta}$ denotes the dependence of the functions $\varphi_{\delta}$ and $\psi_{\delta}$ to $\delta$ by their definitions using $I_n$. Do not forget that the existence of $\delta$ itself depends on the choice of $\epsilon$. So, the value of $\delta$ is a function of $\epsilon$.

By definition of the Lebesgue integral for simple functions we know that:

$$ \int_{[a,b]} \varphi_{\delta} d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n a_i. \mu(I_n) $$

$$ \int_{[a,b]} \psi_{\delta} d\mu = \sum_{i=1}^n b_i. \mu(I_n) $$

So far so good, the problem is that I don't know how I can relate these to the existence of the Lebesgue integral for $f$. In other words I have no idea what inequalities can guarantee the existence of $\int_{[a,b]} f d\mu$.

I'm using this definition: A function $f$ is Lebesgue integrable if and only if there exists a sequence of simple functions which are integrable and uniformly converge to $f$.

I'm not sure how this applies to my case. I'm afraid that I'm not able to show why $\varphi_{\delta}$ or $\psi_{\delta}$ converges uniformly to $f$.

Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: It seems to me that you are done.... $||f - \psi_\delta||_\infty <\epsilon$ and $\epsilon>0$ is arbitrary....

Comment: @John: You mean the uniform norm by $\|.\|_{\infty}$, right?

Comment: Yes, the uniform norm. Now the function $\psi_\delta$ are simple functions and are uniformly closed to $f$. From your definition $f$ is Lebesque integrable. (Of course $\psi_\delta$ are all integrable)

Answer (score 1):

Choose $\varepsilon:=1/n$, (and choose $\delta=:\delta(1/n)$ for that) so that both $\varphi_n:=\varphi_{\delta(1/n)}$ and $\psi_n:=\psi_{\delta(1/n)}$ will uniformly converge to $f$, because of the construction (the proof is John's comment:)
$$\|f-\varphi_{\delta(1/n)}\|_\max \ <\ 1/n$$

Comment: Would you please elaborate on what norm you mean by $\|.\|_{\max}$? I checked the definition of the essential supremum norm, but couldn't relate it to what we have here. If you could explain this in more details I'd be grateful.